# PHP cURL downloaded file is empty

Tags: php, curl, download

So I want to download a mp3 file from a dynamic link, when I run the script it creates test.mp3 but it's empty.

Code :

```
$source = 'http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?
i=yt6MfhzTljRBZ6AjqSsnb2ih1ZifuMoY&e=69';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,0);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);

$destination = "test.mp3";
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

There is nothing in the error.log

**EDIT**
If I add :
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);`

It downloads the source of the page (HTML) but not the mp3 file.

Comment: Do you need to code this or could you just use wget?

Comment: It would be easier with code, I plan to add a POST to change the download link dynamically and return a JSON

Comment: Check if folder is writable.

Comment: Yes, the chmod is set to 777.

Comment: @user2182349 anyways how would you do with wget ? I tried `wget http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=C3CxFT97Oh7cP9kFHc8sZENgiy2Jsaq8&e=79` but it downloads the HTML page.

Answer (score -2):

Because You are not downloading anything.
Check output of your `$data = curl_exec ($ch);`. It must be empty

Comment: is this suppose to be your answer ? use comment box

Comment: I would use it if I had enough repo

Comment: this is not about the repo, you could have told this small thing on comment box

Comment: The link is in the post is outdated, so it doesn't download anything anymore. Anyways the `$data` is empty. I have a cURL error : `Could not resolve host: http`

Comment: @BunkerBoy How it is not? I can't comment without repo.
 KhrysakaLouis I think your code is fine. Or you can use file_put_content($destination, $data);
You just need valid file url.

Comment: @ Andrius go on man use your repo (y), i just suggested you what i thought

Comment: @Andrius so yeah I made a mistake with URL, but it's fine now. If I use `file_put_contents("http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=d1jvOSSnZv4GbzmQ6i04pfOqs5hzoCBM&e=81","test.mp3");` I have this error `failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections`

Comment: Then use it like this

`file_put_contents("music.mp3", fopen("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?video_id=KMU0tzLwhbE&ts_create=1492179861&r=MTk1LjE0LjE2My4xMzg=&h2=b607f530e1b1192b42c38c71ea0824ba&s=146039", 'r'));
`

Comment: Error : `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n`